# Can light destroy auxin?

Tags: plant-physiology, light, plant-perception

In my biology textbook, it says that plants grow towards light because auxin is laterally transferred from the light side to the shaded side, so more auxin stimulates growth and hence the plant bends towards light. My textbook also specifically states that light doesn't destroy auxin. Yet, recently I searched online and find that light will actually destroy auxin by photo-oxidation. I am confused, can someone tell me which is the correct mechanism (or both)? Thanks!